# Finding the volume by Shell method: $y=x^2, y=2-x^2$ about the line x=1

Tags: calculus

Finding the volume by Shell method: $y=x^2, y=2-x^2$ about the line x = 1

what I get from this after graphing is:

$2\pi \int (1-x)(2-2x^2)dx $

which becomes: $2\pi \int (2-2x^2-2x+2x^3)dx $

integrating that I get:

$2\pi[2x- \frac23x^3-x^2+\frac12x^4]   $ from 0 to 1

my answer is $\frac53\pi$ but my book says the answer is : $\frac{16}3\pi$

could someone tell me where I went wrong? was it the upper lower bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the region in the $xy$-plane bounded by the graphs $y=x^2$ and $y=2-x^2$ is symmetric about the $y$-axis, so the projection of this region onto the $x$-axis should be a symmetric interval of the form $[-a,a]$. In this case the points of intersection of the graphs have $x$-coordinates $x=\pm 1$. Thus, your limits of integration should really be from $x=-1$ to $x=1$, not $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is, isn't it symmetric about $y = 1$?

Comment: $y= 2-x^2 = x^2$ when $x=\pm 1$ I agree with though.

Comment: @DisplayName Yes it is, but we're not really interested in that symmetry for this problem.

Comment: I was just referring to "is symmetric about the $y$ -axis". Oh I just realised it was meant to say $x$ axis.

Comment: couldn't you do it for one side? from 0-1 since it is symmetrical?

Comment: @Joshhw No you can't, because the integral is not symmetric. Only the region of integration is.

Answer (score 0):

The limits of the integration is given by where the lines cross each other:
$$ x^2=2-x^2 \Longleftrightarrow x=\pm1 $$
so the limits shold be from -1 to 1.